# Formula to get last value in columns then value of another cell in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a table with rows = `depth` and columns = `value` of the surveys done in each month and year. Not all years/months have surveys so some cells are blank. What I want to do is to determine to which depth each survey has been done, because it is not the same for all years/months. The `depth` values are stored in Column E and the survey `value`s are from Column F to DM.

I was able to call the last value in each column using this formula from [Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LastValueInRowOrColumn.aspx):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX((F1:F111<>"")*(ROW(F1:F111))),COLUMN(F:F)))
```

but this gives me `value` (which I don't need), not `depth`.

I want to know which `depth` (row value) this last `value` corresponds to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDEX($E:$E,MAX((F1:F111<>"")*(ROW(F1:F111))))
```

entered as an array formula in a row outside the range 1:111 and copied across to suit (so probably from F:DM).

Comment: Thanks! This initially worked out for me on the same sheet. But as I tried it on a different sheet (I wanted to compile the data into a new sheet) and I used this formula. It just returned me the value 0.                =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX(('KT SURVEYS'!F1:F200<>"")*(ROW('KT SURVEYS'!F1:F200))),COLUMN('KT SURVEYS'!F1:F200)))

Comment: I could do that but I am using 200 rows in the source sheet, so it would be difficult to use that formula in the same sheet and not get it confused with the rest of the data. I would still need to scroll all the way down to row 201...